# How do I get a refund after purchasing an app from the Mac App store?

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, apple-id

I bought an app and it is so bad despite its low price that I am willing to spend time on getting a refund. How do I get the refunded after an app purchased through the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 4):

Do the following steps

- open up Your Account in iTunes by clicking Account inside iTunes Store
- click see all in the Check Your Purchase History row
- click the Report a Problem button
- select the App from which you want to refund
- explain and write a detailed reason why you think you should get a refund for the app

Comment: I did this once, about 6 months ago. When I try now, the "report problem" button sends me to Apple's support website ... did they change this?

Answer (score 1):

The Mac App Store does not have automatic refund policy. First you have to contact the developer in case of any app issue. But if have bought it mistakenly, then you will not get refund.

For official MAS FAQ : http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4461

Comment: My experience has been an email from the iTunes store, they look you up to see if you've done this alot, asking for refunds--in my case, it was hitting the buy button for a dreadful $10 app in error--and the charge was immediately reversed.

Comment: But this is Mac App Store, not iTunes Store.

Answer (score 0):

The Mac App store doesn't have an equivalent "Report a problem" link that iOS/iTunes app store customers can use to open a support ticket with the store billing support, so you might need to use general Billing Support for any Apple ID issue:

- http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/

You should absolutely be clear (with screenshots if possible) to explain how the application failed to live up to the description that was available to you in the store - if the reviewers at Apple didn't catch a serious problem with the description of the goods as sold, I would expect most people to feel a refund would be a justifiable remedy. You are also free to contact the developer - [reputable developers can and do offer refunds](http://www.omnigroup.com/support/store/refunds/) of either their share of your purchase and some even refund the entire purchase price - in effect paying Apple's cut even when they refunded your cost.

Lastly, you might use the generic feedback page after you have tried to get a refund to document how you felt about the Mac App store, the purchase tools and the complaint resolution process. I have found that nice but plainly honest complaints work best there.

http://www.apple.com/feedback/

There isn't a neat category for third party App Store purchase feedback - so in this case, you might tie it to either the OS or the Hardware as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Always go to the apple refund. Which is Report a Problem about that. If it doesn't help, well maybe call them which may not actually help at all.